# Keras error of fit_generator

Tags: machine-learning, keras

When I call Keras `fit_generator`

```
model_2.fit_generator(train_generator.flow(x_train,y_train,batch_size=batch_size),
                     epochs=100,steps_per_epoch=x_train.shape[0]//batch_size,
                     validation_data=val_generator.flow(x_val,y_val,batch_size=batch_size),validation_steps=250,
                      callbacks=[lrr],verbose=1,initial_epoch=1)
```

it occurs error in unknown reason

I inspect the error message but don`t know what is the problem

`lrr` is below code

```
lrr= ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_accuracy',
                       factor=.01,
                       patience=3,
                       min_lr=1e-5)
```

and the error message is below

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-79080e47cdf0> in <module>
      2                      epochs=100,steps_per_epoch=x_train.shape[0]//batch_size,
      3                      validation_data=val_generator.flow(x_val,y_val,batch_size=batch_size),validation_steps=250,
----> 4                       callbacks=[lrr],verbose=1,initial_epoch=1)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     89                 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name + '` call to the ' +
     90                               'Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2)
---> 91             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     92         wrapper._original_function = func
     93         return wrapper

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit_generator(self, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, validation_freq, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
   1730             use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing,
   1731             shuffle=shuffle,
-> 1732             initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
   1733 
   1734     @interfaces.legacy_generator_methods_support

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_generator.py in fit_generator(model, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, validation_freq, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
     40 
     41     do_validation = bool(validation_data)
---> 42     model._make_train_function()
     43     if do_validation:
     44         model._make_test_function()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in _make_train_function(self)
    314                     training_updates = self.optimizer.get_updates(
    315                         params=self._collected_trainable_weights,
--> 316                         loss=self.total_loss)
    317                 updates = self.updates + training_updates
    318 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     89                 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name + '` call to the ' +
     90                               'Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2)
---> 91             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     92         wrapper._original_function = func
     93         return wrapper

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in symbolic_fn_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     73         if _SYMBOLIC_SCOPE.value:
     74             with get_graph().as_default():
---> 75                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
     76         else:
     77             return func(*args, **kwargs)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/optimizers.py in get_updates(self, loss, params)
    541                 self.updates.append(K.update(vhat, vhat_t))
    542             else:
--> 543                 p_t = p - lr_t * m_t / (K.sqrt(v_t) + self.epsilon)
    544 
    545             self.updates.append(K.update(m, m_t))

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/math_ops.py in binary_op_wrapper(x, y)
    904         try:
    905           y = ops.convert_to_tensor_v2(
--> 906               y, dtype_hint=x.dtype.base_dtype, name="y")
    907         except TypeError:
    908           # If the RHS is not a tensor, it might be a tensor aware object

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py in convert_to_tensor_v2(value, dtype, dtype_hint, name)
   1254       name=name,
   1255       preferred_dtype=dtype_hint,
-> 1256       as_ref=False)
   1257 
   1258 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py in convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, as_ref, preferred_dtype, dtype_hint, ctx, accepted_result_types)
   1312 
   1313     if ret is None:
-> 1314       ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
   1315 
   1316     if ret is NotImplemented:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/constant_op.py in _constant_tensor_conversion_function(v, dtype, name, as_ref)
    315                                          as_ref=False):
    316   _ = as_ref
--> 317   return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
    318 
    319 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/constant_op.py in constant(value, dtype, shape, name)
    256   """
    257   return _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape=False,
--> 258                         allow_broadcast=True)
    259 
    260 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/constant_op.py in _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape, allow_broadcast)
    294       tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(
    295           value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape,
--> 296           allow_broadcast=allow_broadcast))
    297   dtype_value = attr_value_pb2.AttrValue(type=tensor_value.tensor.dtype)
    298   const_tensor = g._create_op_internal(  # pylint: disable=protected-access

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/tensor_util.py in make_tensor_proto(values, dtype, shape, verify_shape, allow_broadcast)
    437   else:
    438     if values is None:
--> 439       raise ValueError("None values not supported.")
    440     # if dtype is provided, forces numpy array to be the type
    441     # provided if possible.

ValueError: None values not supported.
```

As the error message replies something wrong with `callbacks=[lrr],verbose=1,initial_epoch=1`

I changed it to other values for each

but the same thing happens

How to resolve my error?

Comment: Post the compilation part of your model.